# Connecting power source to Arduino's 5V pin

Tags: arduino, power, adapter

I have an Arduino board connected to a Neopixel Ring. This Ring draws more than 0.5 Ampere, so it needs its own power supply (not drawing power via the Arduino board)

I found this schematic that connects a Neopixel and an Arduino to a single power adapter. To my surprise, the power adapter connects its power straight to the 5V pin of the Arduino board.

Arduino seems to advice against this, so my question is: is this the correct way to separately power a device AND an Arduino from one adapter?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is correct, as long as you leave Arduino unpowered via 9...12 V DC plug, because it will draw power from that 5V adapter.

And of course, be sure your adapter can handle the current for both Arduino and that Ring.

Another option would be to power Arduino as usually. Power the Ring through the 5V adapter. Then join the ground on all devices (Arduino, Ring, 5V supply).

Comment: Yes, but then I would have two power supplies which seems kind of clunky. (like having a lamp with two wall plugs)

Comment: @PietBinnenbocht reading the other answer, if you are afraid that reverse voltage will affect regulator, you could add a diode across its output-input pins. Like http://www.hqew.net/files/Images/Article/Circuit_Diagram/dual-variable-regulator-power-supply-5-25v-by-lm7805lm7905.jpg

Comment: I also read the suggestion to take apart a USB cable and use the USB port of the Arduino to connect an adapter. This way you have the benefit of the Arduino's regulator / protection.

Comment: @PietBinnenbocht you could build the USB Power Injector from Everyday Practical Electronics http://www.epemag3.com/proj/0410.html

Comment: Wouldn't it be enough to just split the USB cable like this guy is doing?
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PdDRYY-dxRE

Comment: @PietBinnenbocht it is OK if you leave the +5V from PC unconnected. If voltage from the adapter is slightly higher from that of your PC USB port, it could damage the motherboard. The point is do not power the same device from two different sources.

Comment: people say regulated 5V, but how precisely this has be regulated? What exactly is the tolerance of arduino uno towards being powered this way? I've read it's [6V](https://www.rugged-circuits.com/10-ways-to-destroy-an-arduino/), but how can I verify that?

Answer (score 1):

By doing this, you are applying 5v to the output of the Arduino's on board voltage regulator. Depending on the regulator model, this pratice could damage it, but in most cases I believe it will not. Assuming the regulator on the arduino board is "ok" with this, the only concern left would be if the AC adapter can supply the current you need.

Another approach would be connecting a 9V adapter to the Arduino power input and use a external regulator to down the voltage to 5V only for supplying the LED's.

Comment: Yes but the problem here is that the LEDS will draw a lot of AMPS, more than the Arduino can handle. Hence the external power source that powers the Arduino board and the Leds separately.